# Appium - Clean app state at the first test and last test, but not between tests

Tags: android, python, ios, reset, appium

Background:
I want to test my application in both android and ios simulators using appium. I am running tests in Python and I want to have it so that the workflow of the test will always be the following:

```html
if first test to be ran:
  reset any previous data
  launch simulator and application
  do test
  close application and save state
else:
  launch application
  do test
  close application and save state

if last test:
  reset any saved data
```

I believe the correct way to do this is to include the `--no-reset` server flag, and then use `driver.launch_app()` and `driver.close_app()` between tests, but then I am not sure how to reset any saved data on the last test.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have found a way to remove the data for iOS, the following line can be run in a terminal:   
`xcrun simctl erase <insert UDID here>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using that works:

To clean iOS simulator:

```
xcrun simctl erase <udid here>
```

Note that for iOS simulator, this must be run while the simulator is not open.

To clean android simulator:

```
adb shell pm clear <app package here>
```

Note that for android simulator, this must be run while the simulator is open and the app closed.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly you have a method `start_driver` which creates Appium Driver instance.

Then, pass next capabilities: `fullReset` with `false` value and `noReset` with `true` value. This way `start_driver` method will simply restart app without resetting anything.

To reset app:
1. uninstall app
- iOS: `ideviceinstaller --udid #{udid} --uninstall #{package}`
- Android: you can clear app data `adb -s #{udid} shell pm clear #{package_name}` or uninstall app `adb -s #{udid} uninstall #{package}`
2. call `start_driver`

**UPDATE:** instruction above is for real devices. I didn't notice you are talking about simulators.